# Метод «initDB» с аннотацией @PostConstruct не должен приводить к вызову отмеченного исключения

Tags: java, java-ee, mongodb

Пишу небольшое приложение, реализующее select — insert операции в *MongoDB*. 
Возникла проблема в инициализации базы данных используя метод «initDB» с аннотацией @PostConstruct. 
Код сеансового компонента:

```js
package Library;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Stateless
@Named
public class BookSessionBean {
    
    @Inject Book book;
    
    private DBCollection bookCollection;
    
    /**
     *
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initDB() throws UnknownHostException {
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("booksDB");
        bookCollection = db.getCollection("books");
        if (bookCollection == null) {
            bookCollection = db.createCollection("books", null);
        }
    }    

    
    public void createBook() {
        BasicDBObject doc = book.toDBObject();
        bookCollection.insert(doc);
    }
    
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        
        DBCursor cursor = bookCollection.find();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbo = cursor.next();
            books.add(Book.fromDBObject(dbo));
        }
        
        return books;
    }
}
```

Сама ошибка:

> Метод «initDB» с аннотацией @PostConstruct не должен приводить к
>   вызову отмеченного исключения

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

В `JavaDoc` к `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` пишут:

> Note: A PostConstruct interceptor method must not throw application
>   exceptions

Следует удалить `throws UnknownHostException` из определения метода `initDB()`. Если какие-либо из операций, выполняемых в методе, требуют обработки исключения `UnknownHostException`, то следует выполнять их в блоке `try{...}catch(UnknownHostException){}`.

В блоке `catch` вы можете выполнить на выбор 2 действия:

- Проигнорировать исключение, например, просто выведя сообщение в лог и продолжив исполнение метода. В этом случае контейнер будет считать что компонент инициализирован корректно.
- Обернуть `UnknownHostException` в `java.lang.RuntimeException` и выбросить его (`throw`). В этом случае контейнер "поймёт" что компонент не инициализирован.